# Why showing Error in installing kivyMD (window)

Tags: python, kivymd

I just installed kivy in window, after that I am trying to install kivymd via `python3 -m pip install kivymd` command but it gives error that says `the system cannot execute the specified program`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `CMD` or `command-line-interface` are you using?

Try:

`pip install kivymd`

without mentioning `python`.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-pip-install-in-python/